# Django templatetag return True or False

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm overwriting the index.html of the admintemplate in Django.
I want to add an extra field over the sidebar which should only be displayed if a contition is true.

Here is the important part of m index.html:

```
{% block sidebar %}
<div id="content-related">
{% if action_needed %}
    <div class="my-module">
        <h2>Foobar</h2>
        <p>Display this over the sidebar</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
... Sidebarstuff...
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my templatetag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def action_needed():
    if some_conditon:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The problem is, that the  my-module is displayed all the time.
In another thread i read about using a filter instead of a templatetag, but the Django documentation says, that at least 1 parameter is requiered for a filter. But i simply want a True/False return.

What is the best way to do that?

Edit:
Here is a bit more code to show you what exactly im doing:
I have a Model Account which has a DateTimeField expiration_date to store if the an Account expired.

```
exp = Account.objects.filter(expiration_date__lte = timezone.now())
if len(exp) == 0:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Edit2:
I solved it, but i don't know if it is a very elegant way. Since I dont have enough reputition to answer my own question, I need to share my solution here:

I put the HTML-Code if the  my-module inside the templatetag and return it, if the condition is True:

```
@register.simple_tag
def action_needed():
    if some_conditon:
        return '<div class="my-module"><h2>Foobar</h2><p>Display this over the sidebar</p></div>'
    else:
        return ''
```

In the template now I just call

```
{% action_needed %}
```

Comment: What is `some_condition`? What does it depend on?

Comment: It depends on nothing. Simply checks if there are objects of a Model in my Database

Comment: If your created a filter, it would be possible to pass the name of the Model that is being checked in the database in as the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach (`action_needed` tag returning a boolean + `if` tag) doesn't work cause a templatetag cannot be used as "argument" for another one, so your `{% if action_needed %}` try to resolve a *variable* named `action_needed` in the context.

If the test ("some_condition") depends on some object available in the current context you can use a custom filter applied to this object, ie:

```
@register.filter
def action_needed(obj):
    return some_test_on(obj)

{% if obj|action_needed %}
   whatever
{% endif %}
```

Else, well, you either have to write an assignment tag setting the flag in the context then test the flag or, like you finally did, write a tag doing both the test and returning the appropriate html snippet.

Just as a side note - this :

```
exp = Account.objects.filter(expiration_date__lte = timezone.now())
if len(exp) == 0:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

is a complicated way to write this:

```
return len(Account.objects.filter(expiration_date__lte=timezone.now())) > 0
```

which is an inefficient way to write this:

```
return Account.objects.filter(expiration_date__lte=timezone.now()).exists()
```

Comment: So, my solution is okay? I thought it could be a bit "bad style", if you know what i mean..

Comment: Having templatetags generating html snippets is ok, yes. As to whether it's better to use an assignement tag to set a flag in the context then test for that flag and behave accordingly or to have the templatetag handling both the test and the generation of the html (or plain text or whatever) snippet, it really depends on the concrete use case and your own preferences. My only observation here would be about the naming - `action_needed` is a good name for a predicate but not so for an inclusion tag.

Comment: An [assignmenttag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom template tag that checks if the condition is met. If it is true then render the html between the tags.

```
{% block sidebar %}
<div id="content-related">
{% ifaction %}
    <div class="my-module">
        <h2>Foobar</h2>
        <p>Display this over the sidebar</p>
    </div>
{% endifaction %}
... Sidebarstuff...
{% endblock %}
```

You can see how it is done by looking at the code for Gargoyle's 
[ifswitch tag](https://github.com/disqus/gargoyle/blob/master/gargoyle/templatetags/gargoyle_tags.py).

Comment: Isnt that exactly what I'm already doing? You only removed a space between {% if action %}

Comment: I mean that you create a custom template tag named ifaction instead of using the  standard django if template tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could take here. One idea would be to put the `some_condition` check as a context processor, so it is automatically included in all templates - although that's overkill if you only want it in one template.

A better approach would be to use an inclusion tag. That way, the code currently inside the `{% if action_needed %}` tags would be in a separate template snippet that only gets included if the condition is true. Or, you could use an assignment tag to set a variable in the context, then check it within the `if`.

(Also, note that your code is extremely inefficient, as it potentially involves getting all future `Account` objects. You should do `if exp.exists()` to do a simple existence check instead.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved it in another way. The Problem is, that I can't answer my own question, because I dont have enought reputation...