# having trouble with saving the value of "gender" in update page

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

and I amd making a CRUD project,I have used radio button's for genders:male /female.

I am able to successfully add the genders while adding new employee, however while updating the details, the gender which I selected isnt saved in the 'update' page.

below is the code for gender in the 'Insert' page

```
<tr>
    <td>gender</td>
    <td>
       <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender">male |
       <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender">female 
                            
    </td>
</tr>
```

below is the code for my 'Edit' page

```
Male:<input type="radio" value="{{EmpModel.gender}}">
                            Female: <input type="radio" value="{{EmpModel.gender}}">
```

Since I am not sure what value I am supposed to put here, I added EmpModel.gender for both
please help

Comment: The insert and edit should be the same… while also indicating which one is currently selected. Your edit has the same Callie for both fields as you have guessed in your last sentence.

Comment: I have made it same but now how do I save the data,for example, for an employee named:"Mark" gender:"female", n0ow I go to edit page but "gender" isnt saved and both "female" and "male" option are unselected.

I want the "male" question to be saved whihc isnt happening,how do I do that?

Comment: Maybe have a look at how radio buttons work in html..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, need to put extra attribute **checked**, based on previously selected one.
[mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#try_it)

- use templatetag for returning true/false to checked attribute.[templatetag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998912/django-templatetag-return-true-or-false)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).